# How secure are Redux values in production environment?

Tags: security, redux

Can values stored in the Redux store be spoofed in a production environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume anything on the frontend can be changed and manipulated. You need proper security on your backend to make sure they can't actually do anything you don't want them to.

Assuming you have a `User` object in your redux store. This object has the property `isAdmin: true`

This is fine. You can have various buttons and elements etc shown based on this property. But what you never ever do is allow that single property to ask for data reserved for admins. Your API must make additional checks, like checking a jwt token and making sure that user actually is allowed to view certain data.

A common flow would be:

- User changes his `isAdmin` state, and a button for "Dashboard" pops up on his menu.
- User clicks that button. The client sends a request to the backend to make sure this user is allowed on this page.
- The API responds with `401` error and the user is redirected back away from the secured page.

A common backend strategy is having routes with middleware that checks every request for an `Authorization` header that contains the token.